# Spring oauth - Principal is null

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I am using spring oauth security to protect my rest service. I have an authorization server that works because I get an access_token when I call http://localhost:90001/oauth/token with the right credentials.

I execute the following command in the console:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9001/oauth/check_token?token=55cd2a66-f54a-47f7-b59c-3cea6e2216f5
```

I get a json response displaying the logged in user. So that works. When I try and access a rest endpoint the principal is null. This is my access point:

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
// @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public Principal user(Principal principal) {
    return principal;
}
```

I have a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and a ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter.

My WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter looks like this:

```
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  public WebSecurityConfiguration() {
      super(false);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.csrf().disable();
  }

  @Override
  protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(new CustomAuthenticationProvider()));
  }
}
```

My ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter looks like this:

```
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  public static final String RESOURCE_ID = "MY_RESOURCE_ID";

  @Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
    resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
      .anonymous().and()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/user").authenticated()
      .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(
         new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
  }

}
```

What is the difference between WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter and is there anything in my configuration that is causing Principal for being null.

Thanks in advance,
Martijn

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry. I can't remember what I did. My advice whould be to find a working tutorial and use that.